# How do I plot the predictions made by a LinearRegression model?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I have made a linear regression using sklearn. I am wondering if there is a convenient way where I can plot the prediction versus a specified variable?

Alternatively, is there any other good way of visualising a linear regression model considering it involves n-dimensions?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot visualise the dimensions of an n-dimensional model all at once if n > 3. However, what you can do is plot the pairwise relationships between dimensions. You might want to look into the Seaborn library for visualisation tools.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I actually plot pairwise relationships? Since the model takes multiple inputs from all features and not just 1 at a time